# Adding countdown timer in listview restarts in each new row

Tags: android, xml, android-listview, countdowntimer, custom-adapter

I am getting data from server in XML format and passing it in a `Listview`. In each row added there are to parameters from the `xml` which i want to pass in the `CountDownTimer` so each row has its unique counterdown timer. When i pass the first row the counter works okay but when there is another row added, the timer of the first starts from the beginning. Also when i move the list , the timer of the invisible row starts again from the beginning. How should i pass it so that it is unique for each one and does not changes when changes happen in the `Listview`?

Here is my Adapter:

```
public class PickCallAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CallXML> {

        public PickCallAdapter(Activity context) {
            super(context, R.layout.pick_call_cell, new ArrayList<CallXML>());
        }

        public void setBidProcessMessageThread(final Long tripId) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    setBidProcessMessage(tripId);
                }
            });
        }

        public void setBidProcessMessage(Long tripId) {

            View view = getViewOfList(tripId);

            if (view != null) {
                setTripProgress(tripId, view);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Trips are order by ascending tripid Therefore will use binary search
         * 
         * @param tripId
         * @return
         */
        private View getViewOfList(Long tripId) {

            CallXML[] callXMLs = getItems();

            Integer position = binarySearch(callXMLs, tripId, 0,
                    pickCallAdapter.getCount() - 1);
            if (position != null) {
                int firstPosition = pickCallsView.getFirstVisiblePosition()
                        - pickCallsView.getHeaderViewsCount();
                int cellPosition = firstPosition + position;
                View wanted = pickCallsView.getChildAt(cellPosition);
                return wanted;
            }

            return null;
        }

        public CallXML[] getItems() {

            int size = pickCallAdapter.getCount();

            CallXML[] callXMLs = new CallXML[size];

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                callXMLs[i] = pickCallAdapter.getItem(i);
            }

            return callXMLs;
        }

        /**
         * Using binary search since our list is sorted
         * 
         * @param tripId
         * @param min
         * @param max
         * @return
         */
        private Integer binarySearch(CallXML[] callXMLs, Long tripId, int min,
                int max) {
            if (max < min) {
                return null;
            } else {
                int mid = (min + max) / 2;
                if (callXMLs[mid].getId().compareTo(tripId.intValue()) > 0) {
                    return binarySearch(callXMLs, tripId, min, mid - 1);
                } else if (callXMLs[mid].getId().compareTo(tripId.intValue()) < 0) {
                    return binarySearch(callXMLs, tripId, mid + 1, max);
                } else {
                    return mid;
                }
            }
        }



        @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final CallXML callXML = pickCallAdapter.getItem(position);

            if (callXML == null) {
                return null;
            }

            PickCallViewBuilder pickCallViewBuilder = new PickCallViewBuilder(
                    callXML, TaxiMapGoogle.this);






            TextView timerText = (TextView) pickCallView.findViewById(R.id.timer);
            //pickCallViewBuilder.setTimerText(timerText);


            return pickCallView;

        }

    }
```

and here is my PickCallViewBuilder.java

```
public class PickCallViewBuilder {

    private CallXML callXML;
    private TaxiMapGoogle activity;
    private View cellView;
    private boolean multiplePickUpTimes = false;

    private List<Button> pickUpButtons;
    private Button noButton;

    public PickCallViewBuilder(CallXML callXML,TaxiMapGoogle activity) {
        this.callXML = callXML;
        this.activity = activity;
        definePickUpTimes();
        pickUpButtons = new ArrayList<Button>();
        createView();
    }

    public PickCallViewBuilder setYesButtonListener(OnBidAction onBidAction) {

        List<TimesPerCallXML> timesPerCallXMLs = callXML.getList();

        for(int i=0;timesPerCallXMLs!=null&&i<pickUpButtons.size()&&timesPerCallXMLs.size()>0;i++) {

            for(TimesPerCallXML timesPerCallXML:timesPerCallXMLs) {
                System.out.println("The times per call "+timesPerCallXML.getTimeToPickUp()+" "+timesPerCallXML.getDescription());
            }

            PickCallOnClickListener pickCallOnClickListener = new PickCallOnClickListener(
                    onBidAction,
                    timesPerCallXMLs.get(i).getTimeToPickUp());
            Button pickUpButton = pickUpButtons.get(i);
            pickUpButton.setOnClickListener(pickCallOnClickListener);
        }


        return this;
    }

    public PickCallViewBuilder setNoButtonListener(OnBidAction onBidAction) {

        if(multiplePickUpTimes) {
            noButton = (Button) cellView.findViewById(R.id.fifth_button);
        } else {
            noButton = (Button) cellView.findViewById(R.id.no_button);
        }

        PickCallOnClickListener pickCallOnClickListener = new PickCallOnClickListener(onBidAction,null);

        noButton.setOnClickListener(pickCallOnClickListener);
        noButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        return this;
    }

    public PickCallViewBuilder setDismissButtonListener(OnClickListener dismissClickListener) {

        final Button dismissButton = (Button) cellView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss_button);
        dismissButton.setOnClickListener(dismissClickListener);

        return this;
    }

    private void definePickUpTimes() {

        if(callXML.getList()!=null&&callXML.getList().size()>1) {
            multiplePickUpTimes = true;
        }   
    }

    private void createView() {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if(multiplePickUpTimes) {
            cellView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pick_call_cell_multiple_button, null);
        } else {
            cellView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pick_call_cell, null);
        }

        populateFields();
    }

    public View getView() {
        return cellView;
    }

    private void populateFields() {

        LinearLayout pickUpLayout = (LinearLayout) cellView.findViewById(R.id.pickUpLayout);
        LinearLayout specialLayout = (LinearLayout) cellView.findViewById(R.id.messageLayout);
        LinearLayout distanceLayout = (LinearLayout) cellView.findViewById(R.id.distanceLayout);
        LinearLayout destinationLayout = (LinearLayout) cellView.findViewById(R.id.destinationLayout);
        LinearLayout fareLayout = (LinearLayout) cellView.findViewById(R.id.fareLayout);
        LinearLayout bidLayout = (LinearLayout) cellView.findViewById(R.id.bidLayout);
        LinearLayout paymentLayout = (LinearLayout) cellView.findViewById(R.id.paymentLayout);

        LinearLayout timerLayout = (LinearLayout) cellView.findViewById(R.id.bidLayout2);

        TextView pickUpText = (TextView) pickUpLayout.findViewById(R.id.pickUpLocText);
        TextView specialText = (TextView) specialLayout.findViewById(R.id.specialText);
        TextView distanceText = (TextView) distanceLayout.findViewById(R.id.distanceText);
        TextView destinationText = (TextView) destinationLayout.findViewById(R.id.destinationText);
        TextView fareText = (TextView) fareLayout.findViewById(R.id.fareText);
        TextView companyText = (TextView) distanceLayout.findViewById(R.id.companyText);
        TextView callTypeLayoutText = (TextView) distanceLayout.findViewById(R.id.callTypeLayoutText);
        TextView bidText = (TextView) bidLayout.findViewById(R.id.bidText);
        TextView paymentText = (TextView) paymentLayout.findViewById(R.id.paymentType);

        TextView timerText = (TextView) timerLayout.findViewById(R.id.timer);

        setDistance(distanceText);
        setAddress(pickUpText, pickUpLayout);
        setSpecialNeeds(specialText, specialLayout);
        setCompanyText(companyText);
        setDestination(destinationText,destinationLayout);
        setFare(fareText, fareLayout);
        setCallType(callTypeLayoutText);
        setPaymentText(paymentText);

        setTimerText(timerText);

        setPickUpButtons();
    }


    public void setTimerText(final TextView timerText) {
         final int timetoanswer = (callXML.getRequestWaitTime()+callXML.getClearBiddingTime())*1000;

         new CountDownTimer(timetoanswer, 1000) {

             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                 if (millisUntilFinished >= (callXML.getRequestWaitTime()+1)*1000){
                     timerText.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.biddingtime));
                     timerText.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                 }else{
                     timerText.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.waittime));
                     timerText.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                 }
             }


             public void onFinish() {
                 //timerText.setText("done!");
             }
          }.start();

    }


    private void setDistance(TextView distanceText) {
        double distanceToPassenger = 0.0;

        if(callXML.getDistance()!=null) {
            try {
                distanceToPassenger = Double.parseDouble(callXML.getDistance().replaceAll(",", "."));
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            distanceToPassenger = (double) activity.getDistanceToPoint(
                    callXML.getLat().doubleValue(),
                    callXML.getLng().doubleValue());
            distanceToPassenger /= 1000;
        }

        String measure  = getMeasure(distanceToPassenger);
        int distanceColour = getDistanceColour(distanceToPassenger);

        distanceText.setText(String.valueOf(distanceToPassenger)+" "+measure);
        distanceText.setTextColor(distanceColour);
    }

    private String getMeasure(double distanceToPassenger) {

        String measure = null;
        if(distanceToPassenger < 1) {
            measure = activity.getString(R.string.m);
        } 
        else {
            measure = activity.getString(R.string.km);
        }   

        return measure;
    }

    private int getDistanceColour(double distanceToPassenger) {
        int distanceColor;

        if(distanceToPassenger < 1) {
            distanceToPassenger *= 1000;
            distanceColor = activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.lesskmcolor);
        } else {
            if(distanceToPassenger<2) {
                distanceColor = activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.lesstwokmcolor);
            } else {
                distanceColor = activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.maxkmcolor);
            }
        }

        return distanceColor;
    }

    private void setAddress(TextView pickUpText,LinearLayout pickUpLayout) {
        if(callXML.getGaddress()!=null) {
            pickUpText.setText(callXML.getGaddress());
        }
        else {
            pickUpLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void setSpecialNeeds(TextView specialText,LinearLayout specialLayout) {
        if(callXML.getSpecial()!=null) {
            specialText.setText(callXML.getSpecial());
            specialText.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.deepredcolor));
        }
        else {
            specialLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void setCompanyText(TextView companyText) {
        companyText.setText(callXML.getCompanyName()!=null?" - "+callXML.getCompanyName():"");
    }

    private void setDestination(TextView destinationText,LinearLayout destinationLayout) {
        if(callXML.getDestination()!=null) {
            destinationText.setText(callXML.getDestination());
        }
        else {
            destinationLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void setFare(TextView fareText,LinearLayout fareLayout) {
        if(callXML.getFare()!=null&&callXML.getFare()!=0.0) {

            try {
                fareText.setText(callXML.getFare().toString()+" "+Currency.getInstance("EUR").getSymbol());
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                fareText.setText(callXML.getFare().toString()+" €");
            }
        }
        else {
            fareLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void setCallType(TextView callTypeLayoutText) {
        if(callXML.getCallTypeName()!=null) {
            callTypeLayoutText.setText(" - "+callXML.getCallTypeName());
        } else {
            callTypeLayoutText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void setPaymentText(TextView paymentText) {
        if(callXML.getPaymentType()!=null) {

            String text = paymentTypeString();
            paymentText.setText(activity.getString(R.string.payment_type) + text);
        } else {
            paymentText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void setPickUpButtons() {

        if(multiplePickUpTimes) {
            setPickUpTimesButtons();
        } else {
            setYesButton();
        }

    }

    private void setPickUpTimesButtons() {

        List<TimesPerCallXML> timesPerCallXMLs = callXML.getList();

        for(int i=0;i<timesPerCallXMLs.size();i++) {    
            Button pickUpButton = getPickTimesButton(i);
            setUpPickUpButton(pickUpButton,timesPerCallXMLs.get(i));
            pickUpButtons.add(pickUpButton);
        }

    }

    private void setYesButton() {
        Button yesButton = (Button) cellView.findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
        yesButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pickUpButtons.add(yesButton);
    }

    private Button getPickTimesButton(int timesPerCall) {

        Button yesButton;

        switch (timesPerCall) {
        case 0:
            yesButton = (Button) cellView.findViewById(R.id.first_button); 
            break;
        case 1:
            yesButton = (Button) cellView.findViewById(R.id.second_button);
            break;
        case 2:
            yesButton = (Button) cellView.findViewById(R.id.third_button);
            break;
        case 3:
            yesButton = (Button) cellView.findViewById(R.id.fourth_button);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("an invalid number was provided");
        }

        return yesButton;
    }

    private void setUpPickUpButton(Button button,TimesPerCallXML timesPerCallXML) {
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setTimeText(button, timesPerCallXML);
    }

    private void setTimeText(Button button,TimesPerCallXML timesPerCallXML) {
        if(timesPerCallXML.getDescription()!=null) {
            button.setText(timesPerCallXML.getDescription());
        } else {
            button.setText(timesPerCallXML.getTimeToPickUp()+"'");
        }
    }

    public abstract class OnBidAction {

        public abstract void onBid(Integer pickUpTime);

        public void setButtonVisibility(int visibility) {

            cellView.findViewById(R.id.biddingbuttons).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public class PickCallOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {

        private OnBidAction onBidAction;
        private Integer pickUpTime;

        public PickCallOnClickListener(OnBidAction onBidAction,Integer pickUpTime) {
            this.onBidAction = onBidAction;
            this.pickUpTime = pickUpTime;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            this.onBidAction.onBid(pickUpTime);
        }

    }

    private String paymentTypeString() {

        String paymentStr = callXML.getPaymentType();

        PaymentType paymentType = null;

        try {
            paymentType = PaymentType.valueOf(paymentStr);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            AploonLogger.error("Invalid payment type ", e);
            return paymentStr;
        }

        switch (paymentType) {
        case cash:
            return activity.getString(R.string.cash_payment_type);
        case ccard:
            return activity.getString(R.string.ccard_payment_type);
        case credit:
            return activity.getString(R.string.credit_payment_type);
        case epayment:
            return activity.getString(R.string.epayment_payment_type);
        default:
            return paymentStr;
        }
    }

}
```

my CallXML.java

public class CallXML {

```
public static final String LOG_ERR_TAG = "PARSE";

public static final String INFO_ROOT_CALL_ELEMENT = "tripInfo";
public static final String OLD_ROOT_CALL_ELEMENT = "Call";
public static final String ROOT_CALL_ELEMENT = "PlaceCall";
public static final String ROOT_ASSIGNMENT_ELEMENT = "AssignmentConfirmation";
public static final String CONTENT_ELEMENT = "content";
public static final String ROOT_TYPE_ELEMENTS = "TimesPerCalls";
public static final String ROOT_TYPE_ELEMENT = "TimesPerCall";

private boolean pickedUpCall = false;
private boolean pickedUpPassenger = false;

private Long taxiCompanyId;
private String action;//required
private Integer id; //required
private BigDecimal lat;
private BigDecimal lng;
private String address;
private String gaddress;
private String name;
private Timestamp regtime;
private String special;
private String status;
private String destination;
private String gender;
private String mobile;
private String messageFromServer;
private String driverImei;
private String plateno;
private String deviceId;
private String distance;
private String remarks;
private String companyName;
private Double fare=0.0; 
private String paymenttype;
private String transactionToken;
private String zoneId;
private String zonePosition;
private String callTypeName;
private Integer clearBiddingTime;
private Integer requestWaitTime;
private List<TimesPerCallXML> timesPerCallList;

public String toString() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    return (regtime != null? " [" + sdf.format(regtime) + "] " : "") +
            " Address: " + getFormattedAddress() +
            (name != null? " Name: " + name + " " : "") +
            (special != null? " Special needs: " + special + " " : "");
}

public String getFormattedAddress() {
    return String.format("%s", address == null? gaddress : address);
}

public void update(String address, String gaddress, String special, String destination) {
    setAddress(address);
    setGaddress(gaddress);
    setSpecial(special);
    setDestination(destination);
}

public String getFormattedCompanyName() {
    return companyName != null? "(" + companyName + ")" : "";
}

/**
 * This is a helper method to pass directly the String value as it comes from the XML. 
 * @param fieldName
 * @param value
 * @throws Exception
 */
public void setField(String fieldName, Object value) throws Exception {
            if(!value.toString().equals("null") && !value.toString().equals("(null)")) {
                if (fieldName.equals("id")) {
                    id = Integer.parseInt((String) value);
                } 
                else if(fieldName.equals("taxiCompanyId")) {
                    taxiCompanyId = Long.parseLong((String) value);
                }
                else if (fieldName.equals("action")) {
                    action = (String) value;
                }
                else if (fieldName.equals("address")) {
                    address = (String) value;

                }
                else if (fieldName.equals("gaddress")) {
                    gaddress = (String) value;

                }
                else if (fieldName.equals("name")) {
                    name = (String) value;
                }
                else if (fieldName.equals("regtime")) {
                    try {
                        regtime = value != null? new Timestamp(Long.parseLong((String) value)) : null;
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_ERR_TAG, "Failed to parse Regtime returned in the Call context due to exception: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                else if (fieldName.equals("lat")) {
                    try {
                        lat = new BigDecimal(((String) value).replace(',', '.'));
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_ERR_TAG, "Failed to parse Latitude returned in the Call context due to exception: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                else if (fieldName.equals("lng")) {
                    try {
                        lng = new BigDecimal(((String) value).replace(',', '.'));
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_ERR_TAG, "Failed to parse Longitude returned in the Call context due to exception: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                else if (fieldName.equals("special")) {
                    special = (String) value;
                }
                else if (fieldName.equals("status")) {
                    status = (String) value;
                    if("act".equals(status)) {
                        pickedUpPassenger = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (fieldName.equals("destination")) {
                    destination = (String) value;
                }
                else if (fieldName.equals("gender")) {
                    gender = (String) value;
                }
                else if (fieldName.equals("mobile")) {
                    mobile = (String) value;
                }
                else if (fieldName.equals("msg")) {
                    messageFromServer = (String) value;
                }
                else if (fieldName.equals("driverImei")) {
                    driverImei = (String) value;
                }
                else if (fieldName.equals("deviceId")) {
                    deviceId = (String) value;
                }
                else if (fieldName.equals("plateno")) {
                    plateno = (String) value;
                }
                else if (fieldName.equals("distance")) {
                    distance = (String) value;
                }
                else if (fieldName.equals("remarks")) {
                    remarks = (String) value;
                }
                else if (fieldName.equals("companyname")) {
                    companyName = (String) value;
                }
                else if(fieldName.equals("callTypeName")) {
                    callTypeName = (String) value;
                }

                else if (fieldName.equals("paymenttype")) {
                    paymenttype =(String) value;
                }

                else if (fieldName.equals("fare")) {
                    fare = Double.parseDouble((String) value);
                } 

                else if (fieldName.equals("transactionToken")) {
                    transactionToken = (String) value;
                } 

                else if (fieldName.equals("zoneId")) {
                    zoneId = (String) value;
                } 

                else if (fieldName.equals("zonePosition")) {
                    zonePosition = (String) value;
                } 

                else if(fieldName.equals("clearBiddingTime")) {
                    clearBiddingTime = Integer.valueOf((String) value);
                }

                else if(fieldName.equals("requestWaitTime")) {
                    requestWaitTime = Integer.valueOf((String) value);
                }

    }
}

public Long getTaxiCompanyId() {
    return taxiCompanyId;
}

public void setTaxiCompanyId(Long taxiCompanyId) {
    this.taxiCompanyId = taxiCompanyId;
}

/**
 * Address provided (if any) by the customer during request.
 * @return
 */
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

/**
 * Address determined by the Google location service based upon coordinates automatically provided by customer's GPS enabled device.
 * This address should be more precise over the one provided by customer.
 * @return
 */
public String getGaddress() {
    return gaddress;
}

public void setGaddress(String gaddress) {
    this.gaddress = gaddress;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Timestamp getRegtime() {
    return regtime;
}

public void setRegtime(Timestamp regtime) {
    this.regtime = regtime;
}

public String getSpecial() {
    return special;
}

public void setSpecial(String special) {
    this.special = special;
}

public String getAction() {
    return action;
}

public void setAction(String action) {
    this.action = action;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public BigDecimal getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public void setLat(BigDecimal lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}

public BigDecimal getLng() {
    return lng;
}

public void setLng(BigDecimal lng) {
    this.lng = lng;
}

public String getDestination() {
    return destination;
}

public void setDestination(String destination) {
    this.destination = destination;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getMobile() {
    return mobile;
}

public void setMobile(String mobile) {
    this.mobile = mobile;
}

public String getMessageFromServer() {
    return messageFromServer;
}

public void setMessageFromServer(String messageFromServer) {
    this.messageFromServer = messageFromServer;
}

public String getDriverImei() {
    return driverImei;
}

public void setDriverImei(String driverImei) {
    this.driverImei = driverImei;
}

public String getPlateno() {
    return plateno;
}

public void setPlateno(String plateno) {
    this.plateno = plateno;
}

public boolean isPickedUpCall() {
    return pickedUpCall;
}

public void setPickedUpCall(boolean pickedUpCall) {
    this.pickedUpCall = pickedUpCall;
}

public boolean isPickedUpPassenger() {
    return pickedUpPassenger;
}

public void setPickedUpPassenger(boolean pickedUpPassenger) {
    this.pickedUpPassenger = pickedUpPassenger;
}

public String getDeviceId() {
    return deviceId;
}

public void setDeviceId(String deviceId) {
    this.deviceId = deviceId;
}

public String getDistance() {
    return distance;
}

public void setDistance(String distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
}

public String getRemarks() {
    return remarks;
}

public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
    this.remarks = remarks;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getCompanyName() {
    return companyName;
}

public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
    this.companyName = companyName;
}

public Double getFare() {
    return fare;
}

public String getPaymentType(){
    return paymenttype;
}

public String getTransactionToken() {
    return transactionToken;
}

public String getCallTypeName() {
    return callTypeName;
}

public void setCallTypeName(String callTypeName) {
    this.callTypeName = callTypeName;
}

public String getZoneId() {
    return zoneId;
}

public void setZoneId(String zoneId) {
    this.zoneId = zoneId;
}

public String getZonePosition() {
    return zonePosition;
}

public void setZonePosition(String zonePosition) {
    this.zonePosition = zonePosition;
}

public void setList(List<TimesPerCallXML> list) {
    this.timesPerCallList = list;
}

public List<TimesPerCallXML> getList() {
    return timesPerCallList;
}

public Integer getClearBiddingTime() {
    return clearBiddingTime;
}

public void setClearBiddingTime(Integer clearBiddingTime) {
    this.clearBiddingTime = clearBiddingTime;
}

public Integer getRequestWaitTime() {
    return requestWaitTime;
}

public void setRequestWaitTime(Integer requestWaitTime) {
    this.requestWaitTime = requestWaitTime;
}
```

}

Comment: getView of your Adapter is called each time a cell is becoming visible.
So if you are building a new cell each time getView is called, this cell will have a new countdown. You have to save the current countdown state somewhere else than in the cell.

Comment: can you please provide me an exaxample of what you mean using some code? thnks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part:

```
public void setTimerText(final TextView timerText) {
     final int timetoanswer = (callXML.getRequestWaitTime()+callXML.getClearBiddingTime())*1000;

     new CountDownTimer(timetoanswer, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

             if (millisUntilFinished >= (callXML.getRequestWaitTime()+1)*1000){
                 timerText.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.biddingtime));
                 timerText.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
             }else{
                 timerText.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.waittime));
                 timerText.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
             }
         }


         public void onFinish() {
             //timerText.setText("done!");
         }
      }.start();

}
```

in every iteration of `onTick()` you can store the new value to your `callXML`. Something like:

```
callXML.setRequestWaitTime(int time);
```

EDIT: change your `onTick()` part to:

```
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

             if (millisUntilFinished >= (callXML.getRequestWaitTime()+1)*1000){
                 timerText.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.biddingtime));
                 timerText.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

                 callXML.setClearBiddingTime(callXML.getClearBiddingTime()-1);
             }else{
                 timerText.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.waittime));
                 timerText.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                 callXML.setRequestWaitTime(callXML.getRequestWaitTime()-1);
             }
         }
```

Comment: sorry but i am new to this thing can you provide me a more detailed callXML.setRequestWaitTime(int time); How should it be? thnks in advance

Comment: I don't know what is your CallXML object. Is it your class or from any library? Can you post here CallXML class?

Comment: it does not start now from the beginning the timer but showing wrong time and i think it is because it should not call callXML.setRequestWaitTime(callXML.getRequestWaitTime()-1); as the time i need is the sum of RequestWaitTime+ClearBiddingTime. so should i create a new callXML.setSumTime(time)?

Comment: No, wait, I was wrong, just change my two lines to each other

Comment: it doesnot start from beginning but showing wrong time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95454/discussion-between-alexander-tumanin-and-user2585294).

Comment: hey, did you try my last suggestion in the chat?